# Add status code to each Hapi route

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Is there a way to define the status code to return for each route in Hapi?

For example,

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = [{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/users',
  handler: User.list,
  config: {
    responseCode: 200
  }
}, {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/users',
  handler: User.create,
  config: {
    responseCode: 201
  }
}]
```

**server.js**

```
server.route(routes);
```

Inside the User controller, I'd like to be able to read that `responseCode` like:

```
class Resource {
  constructor() {}

  async request(handler, request, reply) {
    try {
      const response = await handler;
      const statusCode = request.custom.responseCode; // how?
      reply(response).code(statusCode);
    } catch(error) {
      reply(error);
    }
  }
}

class User extends Resource {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  list(request, reply) {
    const getUsers = UserController.list();

    super.request(getUsers, request, reply);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your handler should return response with the desired status code. In that manner you will be able to set code based on your business logic (eg. code 409 if the new user is already existing in the database, for example). You can achieve that by simply wrapping the response in { data, statusCode } object.

Example:

```
const response = { data: users, statusCode: 200 } 
return response;
```

After that you'll be able to access that statusCode:

```
const response = await handler;
reply(response.data).code(response.statusCode);
```

It looks too simple, but there is no need of over-engineering that, really.